# Windows 10 starting at LogonUI.exe + mouse and some keys not working

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot

I have dual booted PC with Windows 10 and Ubuntu.

When I select Windows on boot it is suddenly opening the LogonUI.exe program and asking for me to unlock and then to add my pin. After that, everything looks normal (except for the desktop icons that has blue arrows on them? Compressed?).

It is difficult to follow the guides online as the mousepad and some keys not are functional. I wanted to disable my pin as I read that it can be a reason the computer boots into the LogonUI. I can however not run cmd prompt as administrator as this program (supposedly) "Can't run on this PC". I also wanted to try to boot into safe mode but `bcdedit` is not working either - because I can't run it as admin!

What can I do?